# Displaying accents and other UTF-8 characters in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, character-encoding, uilabel

I have a little app which lists the names of certain people from around the world, and some of those names use characters that are not normal `ASCII` characters, like DÌaz, or ThÈrËse for example.

The strings show up in Xcode just fine, but when I put them in a `UILabel`, they behave unexpectedly.

**My question is:** Is there a way to set up a `UILabel` to to take the exact string in Xcode, and display it properly, even if it is a `UTF-8` character (or any other character encoding for that matter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIKit fully supports unicode, your problem is most likely the encoding of the source file. You can set that in the inspector (Xcode 4: ⌘⌥1) under "Text Settings". Make sure it is UTF-8 as well.

Alternative: Use unicode escapes like `@"\u2605"` (should display ★).

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the String:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithCString:value encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```